# not getting all data updated in database instead i am sending request with all data values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

FlightReservationApplication.java:

```
    package com.shahbaz.flightreservation;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class FlightReservationApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(FlightReservationApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

AbstractEntity.java:

```
    package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities;
    
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class AbstractEntity {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
            
    }
```

UserDetails.java

```
    package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities;
    
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    
    
    @Entity
    public class UserDetails extends AbstractEntity {
        
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        
    }
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.repos;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities.UserDetails;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetails,Long> {


}
```

UserController.java

```
    package com.shahbaz.flightreservation.controllers;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    
    import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.entities.User;
    import com.shahbaz.flightreservation.repos.UserRepository;
    
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
        
        @RequestMapping("/showReg")
        public String showRegistrationPage()
        {
            return "login/registerUser";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value="registerUser",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User theUser)
        {
            userRepository.save(theUser);
            return "login/login";
        }
    }
```

Templates/login/registerUser:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Register User</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>User Registration:</h2>
    <form action="registerUser" method="post">
    <pre>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
    User Name: <input type="text" name="email"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmPassword"/>
    <input type="submit" value="register"/>
    </pre>
    </form>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Templates/login/login

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>User Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Login:</h2>
    <form action="login" method="post">
    <pre>
    User Name:<input type="text" name="email"/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
     <p th:text="${msg}">
     
    </pre>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    
    server.servlet.context-path=/flightreservation
```

I am getting value stored for id,email,and password only in database. Values are not added for firstname and lastname of user_details in
database.

**Output**

```
id  email   firstname   lastname    password
1   abc@gmail.com   null    null    1234
2   pqr@gmail.com   null    null    Pqr12
```

I am unable to recognize the error if someonecan help me out of it

Comment: Change `User` entity name because `User` mysql reversed keyword

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML uses `firstName` and `lastName`, but in `UserDetails`, you are using `firstname` and `lastname` (lower case `n`).

Side note: It is better to use `th:object` and `th:field` for forms with Thymeleaf. See [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) if you want more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion and help problem still facing same issue after changing lower case n to upper case N

Comment: Did you change the field names and the getters/setters in `UserDetails` ?